# OpenGL initial buffer binding target

Tags: opengl

Since binding a buffer to a target such as `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` will modify the state of any bound vertex array object, writing a buffer safely can be tricky.  The easiest solution seems to be to use a buffer target such as `GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER` which does not affect VAO state.

```
void write_buffer(GLint name, int size, const void* data)
{
  // error handling omitted for clarity...
  glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, name);
  glBufferData(GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, size, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

This has the advantage of being safe to call without regard for which OpenGL context is current (assuming you are sharing state) and which VAO is currently bound.

However, according to the OpenGL API reference for `glBindBuffer` the initial target a buffer is bound to may be used as an optimization hint for how the buffer is stored internally:

> Once created, a named buffer object may be re-bound to any target as often is needed. However, the GL implementation may make choices about how to optimize the storage of a buffer object based on its initial binding target.

This means that the above function may hinder optimization if the buffer `name` has not previously been bound to the appropriate eventual target.

The only way I can think of to avoid this penalty is to manually bind the buffer to the desired target immediately after creation and then restore the original binding:

```
GLint create_array_buffer()
{
  GLint original, name;
  glGetIntegerv(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING, &original);
  glGenBuffers(1, &name);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, name);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, original);
  return name;
}
```

Is there a better way to create and fill a buffer safely (with regard to VAOs)?  The process should:

- Preserve the optimization hint of the first binding target
- Not disturb the state of any bound VAO
- Not read state, change state and restore state like I do above

Answer (score 0):

Just binding to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` does not affect a bound `VAO`. Only when `glVertexAttribPointer` is called is the binding state read and put into the `VAO`. Rebinding the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` *does* affect the bound `VAO` state.

This means you are free to change the binding of `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` as long as you make sure to bind the correct buffer before calling `glVertexAttribPointer`.